# SQL Server - 2008 Script writing What is more efficient and How do I tell?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the below 2 queries. Which is more effcient and how would I tell? I've looked at the Execution plan but don't know what I'm looking for, any help would be appreciated.

```
 ;WITH TEST AS

 (SELECT DISTINCT *, DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY T.id 
  ORDER BY T.ID DESC) AS seq_LatestUpdate
           FROM test] t 
                                 )

SELECT *
  FROM  t
INNER JOIN TEST ON T.Id = TEST.Id AND TEST.seq_LatestUpdate = 1
WHERE 1=1
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM [MCS].[JXM1563].[test] t
INNER JOIN (SELECT  DISTINCT T.Id, MAX(ID_CREATEDATE) AS MAXuPDATE
FROM test t
              GROUP BY T.Id 
                                 ) Z ON T.Id = Z.Id
WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: compare execution plans